# Audio Filter for the sound output of my app

Tags: ios, xamarin, audio, xamarin.ios

I am looking for a way to add a low pass audio filter to the sound output from my iOS app.
In the app I am not only playing audio files from the app, also from an webview which is used as a web browser. So it is possible that the audio is played from a external website.
I have seen the Audio Unit Framework but I am not sure how far this goes. Is there a best practice? Other frameworks. docs. or ideas.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apple's native AVFoundation library. It contains the [AVAudioUnitEQFilterType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiouniteqfiltertype) enum as shown below:

```
var engine = new AVAudioEngine();
var nodeEQ = new AVAudioUnitEQ(1);
nodeEQ.GlobalGain = 1;
engine.AttachNode(nodeEQ);
AVAudioUnitEQFilterParameters filter = nodeEQ.Bands[0];
filter.FilterType = AVAudioUnitEQFilterType.LowPass;
```

You can check [this example](https://github.com/ajrotert/On-The-Hunt/blob/5d10e27d019d5939115488dc92bc57ed0bae920b/ARHunter/LowPassAudio.cs#L40) out by [Andrew Rotert](https://developednotdownloaded.com/ContactUs). There is no library that I am aware of but I may be wrong.